# Calling a method from Array.map React

Tags: arrays, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous

I wanted to make a simple function that transforms the index of the array object to an alphabet letter and renders it in my react component. I however ran into a problem.
My Code is:

```js
 class StringList extends Component {
  state = {
    strings: ['String1', 'String2', 'String3', 'String4', ]
  }

  numToChar =i=> {
    return (i >= 26 ? this.numToChar((i / 26 >> 0) - 1) : '') + 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[i % 26 >> 0];
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div> 
        {this.state.strings.map((string, index) => (
            <p>
            {index}, 
            {this.numToChar({index})},
            {this.numToChar(5)}
            //Do other Stuff
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**I expect the result to be:**
0, a, f
1, b, f
2, c, f
3, d, f
...
**However this actually returns:**
0, a, f
1, a, f
2, a, f
3, a, f
...
It is properly incrementing the index, but not when I use it to call my method. Is this because the process is async? If so, how do I use await or promise inside the react render component method? Or is there another way i should be doing this in react? I'm pretty new to react so any additional info helps.

Comment: You're passing an object  (`{index}`)to your function instead of `index`.

Comment: Well, I'm an idiot. Ty that helped.@Shobhit Chittora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render method in React is suppose to be pure, you should be doing asynchronous work outside it. Anyway, this is not required in your problem.

Here is the link to the solution. https://codesandbox.io/s/jv4w87z7vv

Rather than writing complex method for mapping an integer to a character,
you could simply use  `String.fromCharCode(97 + n)`

Also you are passing index as an object `this.numToChar({index})`
rather it is just a variable `this.numToChar(index)`

Comment: Ty, yes the problem was i was using index as object, not as a variable. The 97+n method is great, but i might have over 26 elements, where aa, ab, ac... would be preferable to just continuing to other ASCII characters